# How to test a class method that instantiates non mocked classes in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

This is my first experience in UniTesting and it's giving me headaches when developing the tests, if you could help it would be really nice.

I have in my program something like this:

```
class Baseclass
{
public: 
    Baseclass(Class2 arg) { mProperty = arg};
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();
private:
    Class2 mProperty;
}

class Class1
{
public:
    bool doClass1Stuff();
    ...
}

class Class2
{
public:
    bool doClass2Stuff();
    Class1* getClass1(){return mClass1;};
    ...
private:
    Class1* mClass1; 
}
```

I'm using GoogleTest and gMock to write the tests:

```
class MockClass1 : public Class1
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD(bool, doClass1Stuff,());
};

class MockClass2 : public Class2
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD(MockClass1*, getClass1,());
}
```

I can't solve the problem when testing a method of BaseClass that do something like this:

```
double BaseClass::methodToTest()
{
   Class1* myObject = dynamic_cast<Class1*>(mProperty.getClass1());

   if(myObject.doClass1Stuff())
   {
      //The rest of the code
   }
   return returnValue;
}
```

In the code below: when calling `BaseClass::methodToTest()`, `mProperty.getClass1()` and `doClass1Stuff()` are calling real methods instead of mock methods.

```
TEST(TestSuite1, TestName1){
   MockClass1 * myMockObject1 = new MockClass1;

   MockClass2 * myMockObject2 = new MockClass2;

   BaseClass * testObject = new BaseClass(myMockClass2Object);

   ON_CALL(myMockObject1,doClassic1Stuff()).WillByDefault(Return(true));
   ON_CALL(myMockObject2, getClass1()).WillByDefault(Return(myMockObject1));

   auto var = testObject.methodToTest();

   ASSERT_EQ( 0.0, var);
}
```

How can I make BaseClass call mock methods? Should I modify the source code to test it?

I would appreciate any information you can give me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have object slicing with your BaseClass usage with mock, you need something like:

```
class Baseclass
{
public: 
    Baseclass(std::unique_ptr<Class2> arg) mProperty(std::move(arg)) {}
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();

    double methodToTest()
    {
        Class1* myObject = mProperty->getClass1();

        if (myObject->doClass1Stuff())
       {
          //The rest of the code
       }
       return returnValue;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Class2> mProperty;
};
```

And your TEST, should be similar to:

```
TEST(TestSuite1, TestName1){
   MockClass1 myMockObject1;
   ON_CALL(myMockObject1, doClassic1Stuff()).WillByDefault(Return(true));
   auto myMockObject2 = std::make_unique<MockClass2>();
   ON_CALL(*myMockObject2, getClass1()).WillByDefault(Return(myMockObject1));
   BaseClass testObject(std::move(myMockClass2Object));
   // Note: myMockObject2 is nullptr now, as moved, you no longer can use it for ON_CALL

   auto var = testObject.methodToTest();

   ASSERT_EQ( 0.0, var);
}
```